# Windows search, you should know that .flv files are videos

Tags: windows-search

Windows Search does not appear to recognize flash video files as being video.

I frequently use Windows search to filter files in a folder.  Occasionally I want to look for newly download video files in a folder so I will run a search like `after:yesterday type:video`.  Unfortunately this does not appear to include flash video files.  But it does seem to pick up .wmv, .mp4, and probably other type types.

What do I need to change to get Windows to recognize that a `.flv` file is a video?  Or more generally, how do I force Windows to believe some arbitrary file extension is a certain kind of file.

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: @ChrisF, Windows 7 mostly, but I believe the same search engine is built into vista, 2008, and 2008 R2.  A generic solution that applies to all recent versions of Windows is preferred.

Comment: I have discovered on my work computer this was actually working, and seemed to be related to having the K-Lite Codecs, which I had installed via [ninite.com](http://ninite.com/).  I would still like to know the general steps required to get this working.

Comment: Don't have K-Lite or any codec pack, but when I have FLVs associated with even a self-contained player like VLC, it seems `type:video` includes them. Will have to see what exactly is required for this to work.

Comment: @Karan, that is odd because I have FLV files associated with VLC on my home system and that is where it wasn't working...  This makes me even more curious about what needs to be setup.  I may have to setup a completely clean VM and see if I can capture exactly what is happening during the K-lite install.

Comment: Whoops, seems I was checking in the VM where I wasn't using VLC but KMPlayer. That does register FLVs as a video type for Windows Search, so it must be doing something right that VLC isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently I was miss-understanding what exactly type `type:` search operator does.  I assumed there was some mapping being done somewhere that classified files by extension or mime-type, but that is not what is happening..

The `type:` seach operator will match the the text that is displayed the `Type` column.  When VLC is set as the default application for files matching `*.flv` the text displayed in the `Type` column is `VLC media file (.flv)`.

[image: Windows Type]

The type text when VLC is the default program is defined like this.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VLC.flv]
@="VLC media file (.flv)"
```

Adjusting that value to something like `VLC video file` and restarting explorer makes it so that a search for `type:video` displays `*.flv` files when VLC is set as the default program.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but here's what I'd suggest:

- Open up `regedit`.
- Head to computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
- Find (or create) the `.flv` key.
- Inside that key, add a new String (REG_SZ) named `PerceivedType` and set it's value to `video`.
- Close Regedit and reboot.

Comment: I have discovered the answer.